# Why does lubridate's parse_date_time work with lapply, but fail with sapply?

Tags: r, lapply, sapply, lubridate

**Given**: the following 4x2 dataframe

```r
df <- as.data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  matrix(
    c("2014-01-13 12:08:02", "2014-01-13 12:19:46",
      "2014-01-14 09:59:09", "2014-01-14 10:05:09",
      "6-18-2016 17:43:42",  "6-18-2016 18:06:59",
      "6-27-2016 12:16:47",  "6-27-2016 12:29:05"),
    nrow = 4, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE
  )
)
colnames(df) <- c("starttime", "stoptime")
```

**Goal**: the same dataframe but with all the values replaced by the return value of the following `lubridate` function call:

```r
f <- function(column) {
  parse_date_time(column, orders = c ("ymd_hms", "mdy_hms"), tz = "ETZ")
}
```

Here's the `sapply` call, whose result contains strange integers:

```r
df2 <- sapply(df, FUN = f) # has values like `1467030545`
```

And here's the `lapply` call, that works as expected:

```r
df2 <- lapply(df, FUN = f) # has values like `2016-06-27 12:29:05`
```

I understand `sapply` returns the simplest data structure it can while `lapply` returns a list. I was prepared to follow up the `sapply` call with `df2 <- data.frame(df2)` to end up with a data frame as desired. My question is:

***Why*** does the `parse_date_time` function behave as expected in the `lapply` but not in the `sapply`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that `sapply` have by default `simplify = TRUE` and when the length or dimension of the `list` elements are same, it simplifies to a `vector` or `matrix`.  Internally, Date time classes are stored as numeric,

```
typeof(parse_date_time(df$starttime, orders = c("ymd_hms", "mdy_hms"), tz = "ETZ"))
#[1] "double"
```

while the `class` is 'POSIXct`

```
class(parse_date_time(df$starttime, orders = c("ymd_hms", "mdy_hms"), tz = "ETZ"))
#[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

so it coerces to that while doing the `matrix` conversion, while in the `list` it preserves the `class` format.

If we are interested in a `data.frame`, then we create a copy of 'df' and use `[]` to get the same structure as 'df'

```
df2 <- df
df2[] <-  lapply(df, FUN = function(column) {
     parse_date_time(column, orders = c("ymd_hms", "mdy_hms"), tz = "ETZ")
   })

df2
#           starttime            stoptime
#1 2014-01-13 12:08:02 2014-01-13 12:19:46
#2 2014-01-14 09:59:09 2014-01-14 10:05:09
#3 2016-06-18 17:43:42 2016-06-18 18:06:59
#4 2016-06-27 12:16:47 2016-06-27 12:29:05
```

Comment: your last remark about using df2[] to get lapply to return something of the same structure as df2... where can I learn about that, what is it called?

Comment: @Captain_Obvious See, for instance, [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html#subassignment).